# Javascript syntax issue sessionStorage values to setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer

First of all I should say that I am not very experienced with JavaScript and I would like some help on passing a sessionStorage value to a setting.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.userSettings = null;

    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function () {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                title: "TestRadio",
                mp3: "http:/streamlink"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "jplayer/dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "mp3",
        wmode: "window",
        volume: "75",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        loop: true,
        autoBlur: true,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        remainingDuration: false,
        toggleDuration: false
    });
});

function storeUserjPlayerSettings(){

var settings = new Object();

settings.volume = $("#jquery_jplayer_1").data().jPlayer.status.volume;
settings.paused = $("#jquery_jplayer_1").data().jPlayer.status.paused;
settings.src = $("#jquery_jplayer_1").data().jPlayer.status.src;

sessionStorage.setItem('userjPlayerSettings', JSON.stringify(settings));
window.userSettings = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('settings'));
}
```

What I would like to do is to pass the settings.volume web stored value to the volume parameter

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function () {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    title: "TestRadio",
                    mp3: "http:/streamlink"
                });
            },
            swfPath: "jplayer/dist/jplayer",
            supplied: "mp3",
            wmode: "window",
            **volume**: "75",
            useStateClassSkin: true,
            loop: true,
            autoBlur: true,
            smoothPlayBar: true,
            keyEnabled: true,
            remainingDuration: false,
            toggleDuration: false
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just do the same thing as you do in `storeUserjPlayerSettings `, namely `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('settings'))` and access the `volume` property?

Comment: @FelixKling thank you for answering. Honestly, I came across this solution online but for me it's really hard to get it to work. It would be very helpful if you could provide me with a small snippet on how the code should look like.

Comment: oh, it turns out that this is the answer you took from, it would have probably been useful if you linked it in your question.

Instead of `getItem('settings')`, do `getItem('userjPlayerSettings')`. I'll update that in the other answer in that thread. You can check if it has worked by debugging in your web browser and looking at the value of `volume`.

Comment: Duplicated post is incorrect. The answer is the same that in this question. OP needs to solve the inverse task. I vote to reopen. And there is a correct answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving the volume earlier, so you just access it in the reverse process when you need it.

For example, change the `volume: 75` initialization to a call to a function that get the volume from your saved settings: `volume: volumeSetting()`.

Here's an example of how you might write that function itself:

```
function volumeSetting() {
  var settings = sessionStorage.getItem("userjPlayerSettings");
  if (settings != null) {
     settings = JSON.parse(settings);
     if (typeof settings.volume == 'number')
       return settings.volume;
  }
  return 75;
}
```

Comment: A little explanation is useful. Maybe some of us understand fine this code, but OP is telling us it's hard for him since the original code was substracted from a webpage. Explain the code and I will upvote you. The rules in stackoverflow forbids a _link-only_ and a _code-only_ answers, since there aren't useful.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude good point, thanks

Comment: You are welcome, I see your reputation and I think you are not very familiar with the behaviour of this site, but all is learning proccess ;) My upvote to you. Good luck!